# How to access the {exefile}.appconfig settings file

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How is it possible to access the {exefile}.appconfig  settings file?

It is mentioned in many tutorials, but how can I get to it in Visual Studio?

Comment: You mean, how to open it up and edit it? If editing in VS, then you're looking for app.config in console apps, desktop apps and web.config for websites.

Comment: @Hammerstein I cant see one present in my console app

Comment: Hmm. yes, not in console apps. You can add one, add new file|General, application configuration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the configurations of the  section of the App.config then:

1. Add the a reference System.Configuration to your project.
2. Use the ConfigurationManager class like this:

`var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"];`

Another option is to use Visual Studio to manage your Settings:

1. Double click in the Solution Explorer at "Properties".
2. Open the tab "Settings".
3. Click into the center of the tab and then enter you settings.